# How to select specific key/value of an object in json via python

Tags: python, json, api

I'm able to get response of api request and have it give me all the details. I decode the json response.json() and create the file with open() and json.dump. I am able to see all the keys and values of the object in the list. Next I would like to get a specific key/value so I can use it as an input to my other python script.

I am able to request from api and decode the json and create json file via json.dump and list all of the objects.

My python code to query and create the json file.

```
import requests
import json

#API request details
url = 'api url'
data = '{"service":"ssh", "user_id":"0", "action":"read_by_user", 
"user":"D2", "keyword":"NULL"}'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

#Making http request
response = requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers,verify=False)
print(response)

#Json string
json_disco = response.text
print(type(json_disco))
print(json_disco)

#Decode response.json() method to a python dictionary and use the data
device_disco = response.json()
print(type(device_disco))
print(device_disco)

with open('devices.json', 'w') as fp:
  json.dump(device_disco, fp, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

This is the code that i use netmiko module to access equipment

```
with open('devices.json') as dev_file:
  devices = json.load(dev_file)
print(devices)

netmiko_exceptions = (netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException,
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoAuthenticationException)

for device in devices['device']:
  try:
    print('~' * 79)
    print('Connecting to device:',device['ip'])
    connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
    print(connection.send_command('show interfaces'))
    connection.disconnect()
  except netmiko_exceptions as e:
    print('Failed to ', device['ip'], e)
```

To access ssh to the devices in array 'device['ip'] which refer back to the json file that contain all the details such as login name/ip/password.

JSON response from api query that response all the details are below;
FROM THIS....

```
{
   "status": "SUCCESS",
   "device": [
         {
             "model":"XXXX-A",
             "username": "login1",
             "ip": "10.10.10.1",
             "password": "123",
             "device_type": "cisco_ios"
         },
         {
             "model":"XXXX-A",
             "username": "login2",
             "ip": "10.10.10.2",
             "password": "456",
             "device_type": "cisco_ios"
         },
         {
             "model":"XXXX-A",
             "username": "login3",
             "ip": "10.10.10.3",
             "password": "test",
             "device_type": "cisco_ios"
         }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract only the key and value of username, ip and password and still in the json format below.
TO THIS....

```
{
      "status": "SUCCESS",
      "device": [
            {
                "username": "login1",
                "ip": "10.10.10.1",
                "password": "123"
            },
            {
                "username": "login2",
                "ip": "10.10.10.2",
                "password": "456"
            },
            {
                "username": "login3",
                "ip": "10.10.10.3",
                "password": "test"
            }
      ]
 }
```

I am not able to extract specific keys and values from each object and print in json list format as above.

This question is part of one if my other posts but I made it a separate question as that post was already answered and to avoid any confusion. I really need expert help, support and guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and dict like this:

```
device_disco["device"] =[dict(username=k1["username"],password=k1["password"],ip=k1["ip"]) for k1 in 
device_disco["device"]]

jsonData = json.dumps(device_disco)
print (jsonData)
```

in your code:

```
import requests
import json

#API request details
url = 'api url'
data = '{"service":"ssh", "user_id":"0", "action":"read_by_user", 
"user":"D2", "keyword":"NULL"}'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

#Making http request
response = requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers,verify=False)
print(response)

#Json string
json_disco = response.text
print(type(json_disco))
print(json_disco)

#Decode response.json() method to a python dictionary and use the data
device_disco = response.json()
print(type(device_disco))
print(device_disco)
device_disco["device"] =[dict(username=k1["username"],password=k1["password"],ip=k1["ip"]) for k1 in 
device_disco["device"]]

jsonData = json.dumps(device_disco)


with open('devices.json', 'w') as fp:
json.dump(jsonData, fp, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: Hi thanks sir. The details of name/ip/etc is getting via private api (i have no control of this api and I can make my request based on api provided) and the content might be change and updated. I can get all the details and from there I hope I can modified which key/value that i require (this part is my problem). Also the key/value that i require shall maintain in the json format {"device":[{},{},{}]}.

Comment: @chenoi check my edited answer , you just need to convert jason data to dict and then do the process

Comment: Hi sir the json convert json.loads() will not list the keys/values (username,ip,password) that i want....it will load everything..

Comment: After loading whole json data to variable you can use my code

Comment: the data call from api can be change from time to time, thus i need to request it every time i want to access the devices to ensure im getting the latest update ip/username/password... i cannot every time have to hardcoded the json string in my code...

Comment: is your json data in device_disco?

Comment: Looks good...i will simulate and run it to be verified further. Thanks

Comment: Yes sir. it works. Thanks for your attention and good support.

Comment: @chenoi glad i could help.

Answer (score -2):

Try this working code:

```
import json
import sys

data={
   "status": "SUCCESS",
   "device": [
         {
             "model":"XXXX-A",
             "username": "login1",
             "ip": "10.10.10.1",
             "password": "123",
             "device_type": "cisco_ios"
         },
         {
             "model":"XXXX-A",
             "username": "login2",
             "ip": "10.10.10.2",
             "password": "456",
             "device_type": "cisco_ios"
         },
         {
             "model":"XXXX-A",
             "username": "login3",
             "ip": "10.10.10.3",
             "password": "test",
             "device_type": "cisco_ios"
         }
    ]
}
json_str = json.dumps(data)
resp = json.loads(json_str)
print (resp['device'][0]['username'])
```

Comment: Hi thanks sir. I just need few keys/values from all the keys listed.

Comment: Here is the working code for you:

    import json
    import sys
    
    data={put you JSON here}
    
    json_str = json.dumps(data)
    resp = json.loads(json_str)
    print (resp['device'][0]['username'])

Answer (score -2):

```
print(json.dumps(json_object['defaultName'], sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```